# Websocket and Rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, websocket

I am new to the web socket framework with Rails and generally I feel I should get my hands to start working with it. I have used Faye for my private message publishing and it works nicely. So I want to ask if there is a nice tutorial out there that can show me how to use web sockets with rails. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to use web sockets with Rails? Do you have a specific type of functionality in mind that wouldn't be solved with a node.js + socket.io server communicated with via AJAX?

Comment: i would like to use it for private messaging like charting

Answer (score 1):

Node.js + socket.io is probably your easiest option right now. Faye is set up to use Node.js, so you may have already have Node.js running alongside your rails app (depending on how you're using Faye). You'll just want to start using [socket.io](http://socket.io). The socket.io [repo](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) includes some very useful examples - I sugget looking at [chat](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat).

You can communicate between your rails app and Node.js server via http. Node.js lets you easily make an http server. You may also want to take a look at [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).